# HTML conversion issue while sending multiple mails in php mailer

Tags: phpmailer

We are facing one issue while sending one by one mail through loop using PHP mailer. Whenver sending mails one by one , the body of the mail part is getting encoded  only for some recepient and for some other others body part is coming fine. please have a look in to the code we have used.

```
    try {

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled
            $mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
            $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
            $mail->CharSet='UTF-8';
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP server port
                $mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com"; // SMTP server
                $mail->Username   = "mylogin@gmail.com";     // SMTP server username
                $mail->Password   = "mylogin";            // SMTP server password
                $mail->From       = "testo@host.com";
                    $mail->FromName   = "$frommailid";
                $mail->Encoding    = 'base64';
                $mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n';            
                    $to =$offmailid;
                if($ccmailid!='')
                {
                $mail->AddCC($ccmailid);
                }
                $to='test@gmail.com';
                $mail->AddAddress($to);
                $mail->Subject  =$subject;
                $mail->AltBody  = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
                $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML        
                $mail->Send();
                //echo "mail sent";
        } 
        catch (phpmailerException $e) 
        {
              //    echo $e->errorMessage();

        }



output :


y="----=neXtPaRt_1413635021"


------=neXtPaRt_1413635021
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b1_d42b7a92f948fa93f11ba35ba7f81fe2"

--b1_d42b7a92f948fa93f11ba35ba7f81fe2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VG8gdmlldyB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZSwgcGxlYXNlIHVzZSBhbiBIVE1MIGNvbXBhdGlibGUgZW1haWwg
dmlld2VyIQ0K


--b1_d42b7a92f948fa93f11ba35ba7f81fe2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

RGVhciBUZXN0ZW1wbG95ZWUgLDxicj48YnI+IFlvdXIgbGVhdmUgZnJvbSBPY3QgMjEsMjAxNCB0
byBPY3QgMjEsMjAxNCBhcHBsaWVkIG9uIE9jdCAxOCwyMDE0IGhhcyBiZWVuIGFwcHJvdmVkLjxi
cj48YnI+Q29tbWVudHMgOjxicj48YnI+IFJlZ2FyZHMsPGJyPlNoaW1uYSBDPGJyPlNvZnR3YXJl
IEVuZ2luZWVyPGJyPg==



--b1_d42b7a92f948fa93f11ba35ba7f81fe2--



------=neXtPaRt_1413635021
Content-Type: text/plain;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things wrong here - you're trying to do things that PHPMailer is already doing for you, and probably breaking it.

Most obvious thing is setting ContentType - just don't do that.

Calling msghtml sets ishtml and also sets altbody, so you don't need to do them either.

I'd strongly suggest you don't use Base 64 encoding - use quoted-printable encoding.

Don't use ssl on port 465. Use tls on port 587.

This all looks like you started from an old example - are you running the latest from Github?

Comment: i have downloaded latest phpmailer from sGithub - till not working

Comment: Did you do any of the other things I suggested? "Still not working" is not any use for telling you what the problem is.

Comment: I have done all changes whatever you have suggested. After changing "SSL" to "TLS" on port 587 it works fine for all mails.I have added the below mentioned code.                                                      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587; port
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer     ="smtp";                                      this works fine. thanks Synchro.